# ActiveRecord errror "row containing the LOB value is not locked" in Oracle

Tags: oracle, activerecord

In a Rails app I have a Company ActiveRecord Object and one of its field is a :text. This app must to work (please don't ask why... is my boss decision) in mysql and Oracle. in mysql works without problem (is a text datatype), but in Oracle is a CLOB and every time I tried to save (a new object or updated a existing one), this error appear:

ORA-22920: row containing the LOB value is not locked

I have the activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.3.0 Adapter.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model class, you need to set partial_udpates = false.
Rails doesn't do the select ... for update needed for Oracle LOBs.